# Correctly binding the tab key in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tabs, keyevent

I'm trying to override the standard behavior of the tab key inside the tkinter text widget.  I was trying

```
from tkinter import *


def enter_return(event):
    print("Return")


def enter_tab(event):
    print("Tab")


root = Tk()
t = Text(root, height=20, width=30)
t.pack()

t.bind_all('<Return>', enter_return)
t.bind_all('<Tab>', enter_tab)
mainloop()
```

but when I run that code, only the `enter_return()` function is called when I press the return key. When I press the tab key, `enter_tab()` is not called. Why is that and how can I fix it?

I'm on windows.

Comment: Use `.bind(...)` instead of `.bind_all(...)`. Also you might want to `return "break"` from your `enter_tab` function, if you don't want the tab to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `t.bind_all('<Tab>', enter_tab)` to `t.bind('<Tab>', enter_tab)` solved my problem. However, I do not understand why and why is `t.bind_all('<Return>', enter_return)` still working, in contrast.

Answer (score -1):

```
root.bind("<Tab>", enter_tab)
```

Hopefully binding the Tab key event to the main window will achieve your goal

Comment: Do you want OP to literary use `root.bind("", enter_tab)`? Or do you want OP to use `root.bind("<Tab>", enter_tab)`? If the latter one, please make it a bit more obvious.

Comment: It didn't work. Besides, `bind_all` should bind it to all widgets, including root?!